# Database denormalization: multiple rows into single column. How bad is it?

Tags: sql-server-2008, denormalization

We have few join-heavy queries to our SQL Server 2008 database and in an attempt to optimize them I thought of having a view that would produce this

```
OrderID     Number    Traveller
1           102       1015;John Doe|1016;Jon Appleseed
```

out of

```
OrderID     Number
1           102


TravellerID    OrderID    FullName
1015           1          John Doe
1016           1          Jon Appleseed
```

My question is: how bad is it from a DBA's standpoint? On the one hand, it gets the job done, but this solution really bothers the purist side of me.

Comment: Do you plan to further use these views by joining them to other tables (or - the horror - to similar views) using these columns?

Comment: How heavy are your join queries? Do you have proper indexing/statistics? If so you should have no trouble with the joins, as opposed to the non-relational-like view

Comment: What will the results be used for? If it's for some type of report, perhaps what you need to do is cache the result and invalidate when the data source changes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the views are going to be queried.  If the purpose is to do something like

```
SELECT OrderID from dbo.vw_Orders WHERE Traveler like '%Jon Appleseed%'
```

then you should **NOT** do this.  If you are just using the view to return a list that will be parsed by your application, then it may not be so bad.