# Are de-normalised tables preferred in any aspect of a project?

Tags: sql-server, denormalization

While going through interview , My Interviewer asked me a question about Denormalization of tables and its usage in applications.

On guess, I answered, Yes it might be. Being denormalized , you have all columns in a single table where you do not require any kind of joins so your biggest plus point will be performance if proper look up conditions are given. And you can use a denormalized table in Reportings.

Is it correct, what I answered?

Comment: This is not a very useful question as stated because it seems to be asking for opinions, about projects, and it's about an interview you had - a good answer that is useful to you would have to know something about the interviewer and what they were trying to learn about you. This doesn't make for a very useful post for anyone else on this site, unless they are also interviewing for the same position with the same person.

Comment: Typically a 3NF DB doesn't slow down lookups *much* but sometimes it can be reasonable to denormalize. A phrase I've heard, and like to repeat, is "Normalize until it really hurts, then de-normalize until it works"

Comment: I'm not going to iron fist this one but when it gets closed I suggest you re-word it to ask about pros and cons of denormalization without mentioning interviews / projects or whether your answer was "correct." Or just [read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) [about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534128/) [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc505841.aspx) [information](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44530/). All 4 links were in the top 10 [Google results for "denormalization in SQL Server"](http://google.com/search?q=denormalization+in+sql+server) BTW.

Comment: @AaronBertrand , thats what I was looking for. I had this article once, but was not getting where I had read that. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: There *is* a good question buried in there. The problem is that right now it's stated as asking about the topic as a whole, about which I'm sure entire books have been written (AKA it really "does depend"), so it's not a good fit for this format. If the question was about a much more specific situation, we could certainly tackle that.

Answer (score 6):

Actually the performance can be slower when you have to update the data, which is why denormalization is not normally used as default in OLTP systems.

OLAP - reporting - uses them as well as precalculated aggregates because updates do often not happen in real time but batched and query performance can be paramount.

But for anything transactional - denormalization is not advisable as default approach in application development.

By the way, unless you do reporting denormalization can make your data access slower because while you do not have a join, the table may be a LOT bigger, thus requiring more RAM or more IO budget to answer the same query.

Comment: Looks like your `z` and `y` keys have got muddled!

Comment: No totlly. switching german and polsh keyboards at the moment every couple of minutes.

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  This is a good summary of some of the reasons to use or avoid denormalization.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades Yeah that is weird.  There's nothing wrong with this answer other than the y-z key-switch.  Which is obviously a typo problem and easily fixed.